# UICollectionView under Navigation Bar, but not under Tab Bar

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that I want to go under the navigation bar. Basically I want it to ignore the entire top safe area, yet still want it to respect the bottom safe area, as there's a tabbar there. This is how it currently looks:

[image]

But I want the first cell to start directly the very top of the screen, under the (translucent) navigation bar and the status bar.

If I set `collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`, then the top part works great, but then the bottom part of the collection view content is hidden by the tabbar - you can't scroll all the way to the bottom so to speak. So I have to manually add a bottom inset again? How do I get the height of the tabbar, including any bottom safe area on devices that have the home bar? Or is there a better way to tell the collectionview to ignore only the top area for its content inset adjustment?

Comment: Have you try to change collectionview's Y position programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set the bottom content inset of the collection view manually, after setting the adjustment behavior to `.never`.

The correct inset (including the tab bar and any home bar) can be found in `safeAreaInsets`.

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
collectionView.contentInset.bottom = collectionView.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

You'll need to do this at a point when the `safeAreaInsets` have been set, such as `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

As far as I remember, it used to be possible by simply adjusting the `edgesForExtendedLayout` property of the containing view controller, but that was phased out when safe areas were introduced in iOS 11 I believe.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was almost there. But every time I was printing out `collectionView.safeAreaInsets.bottom` it was 0 - because I was doing it in `viewDidLoad`. Big sigh to iOS :)

Comment: Ha that's got me plenty of times... Good old view lifecycle eh